# I am unable to register service worker for PWA

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

- I am trying to register PWA for my react app. I am unable to do so.
- Framework I have used is react framework to develop the app.
- I followed the step mentioned in a blog but it is not responding when I perform lighthouse from the dev tools.
- Here is my "index.js" file, I have enabled the service worker to register().

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Currently the app will not work  in offline we need to setup service workers for that
serviceWorker.register();
```

- I have also added the service worker in index.html, here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>SS-RPA</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      .navbar {
        background-color: #4169e1;
      }
      .navbar h3 {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .navbar a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .page-info {
        padding: 10px;
      }
      .Current {
        color: #2e8b57;
      }
      .Completed {
        color: #ff6347;
        text-decoration: line-through;
      }
    </style>


  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('/worker.js').then(function(registration) {
            console.log('Worker registration successful', registration.scope);
          }, function(err) {
            console.log('Worker registration failed', err);
          }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          });
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Service Worker is not supported by browser.');
      }
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

- And I have also added the worker.js file in my public directory where index.html and manifest.json resides.

```
worker.js 

var CACHE_NAME = 'ss-rpa';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/',
  '/completed'
];

// Install a service worker
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});

// Cache and return requests
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
      }
    )
  );
});

// Update a service worker
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  var cacheWhitelist = ['pwa-task-manager'];
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

- I don't know whether I have not imported everything well or I am missing out anything.
- Here is the output of the dev tools Lighthouse
  [image]
- Thanks !!!

Comment: I think in react the 'serviceWorker.js' need to be created when creating a new project, do you have this file?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to: `serviceWorker.register();` in `index.js`.
The only problem in your app is you serve it with: `npm start`. To have PWA application you have to make build of your code and then serve it with `HTTPS` protocol.
To make build: `npm run build`

One of the needs of `PWA` applications is serve with `HTTPS` protocol.

Hope to be useful. Also sorry about my English.

Comment: Still I am getting the same error. I tried what you said. I ran the ```npm run build``` in the client folder. Still the same.

Comment: Did you serve build with HTTPS portocol?

Comment: Yes I used ```set HTTPS=true&&npm run dev```